# Antlr Lexer and Parser for catching exressions within another expression

Tags: antlr4

I need to get the pieces of text out of text)). Very simple example actually, but gives me quite some pain.

Here is the sample text, it is an email template:

```
{!Account.Name} 

Hi hi there {!Account.Id + 'cool'}. 

Very interesting stuff - {!Contact.Description} 

Now we get {!Contact.Description + Contact.Email__c}
```

So I need all the occurances of text like Account.Name, but only those which are within opening "{!" and closing "}" tags.

What is the simplest/starting approach to do it? Note that in case of the last line, I need to get the two occurances, Contact.Description and Contact.Email__c.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Why not use an existing templating engine?

Comment: It is not accessible to me, only text is accessible, it runs in cloud and we do not own the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do a plain text search for `{...}` blocks and parse their content with a simple expression parser. Don't try to come up with a parser that gets all the text and must be prepared to deal with any rubbish that can come in outside of the blocks (which could ultimatively lead to security problems).

Comment: How would the simple expression parser look like for my case then?

Comment: That depends of course on what you want to parse in such blocks, but you can always take one of the existing expression rules (e.g. [in the Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/JavaParser.g4#L462)) and adjust them to your needs.